# if $f(x+3\pi)=f(x)$ where $f(x)=\cos{(nx)}\sin{(\frac{4}{n}x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n$ be integer number,if $$f(x)=\cos{(nx)}\sin{(\dfrac{4}{n}x)}$$
such $f(x+3\pi)=f(x),\forall x\in R$

Find $n$

since
$$2f(x)=\sin{\left(\left(\dfrac{4}{n}+n\right)x\right)}+\sin{\left(\left(\dfrac{4}{n}-n\right)x\right)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We notice almost immediately that if $n=2$, then $f(x)=\cos2x\sin2x=\frac{1}{2}\sin4x$, and so $f(x+3\pi)=f(x)$. But, although we are not specifically asked for all possible values of $n$, we may as well look for them. Indeed, if $n=-2$, then $f(x)=-\cos2x\sin2x$, which also works.

For any $n$ we have $f(x+6\pi)=\cos(nx)\sin(\frac{4x}{n}+\frac{12\pi}{n})$, so for the condition to hold we require $\sin\frac{4x}{n}=\sin(\frac{4x}{n}+\frac{12\pi}{n})$ to hold for all $x$, which it clearly cannot for $|n|>3$.

$f$ is undefined for $n=0$, so we rule out that value. For $n=1$ we have $f(x)=\cos x\sin4x$ and $f(x+3\pi)=\cos(x+\pi)\sin4x=-f(x)$, which fails. Similarly, for $n=-1$ we have $f(x)=-\cos x\sin4x$ and again $f(x+3\pi)=-f(x)$. For $n=3$ we have $f(x)=\cos3x\sin(\frac{4x}{3})$, and $f(x+3\pi)=\cos(3x+\pi)\sin(\frac{4x}{3}+\pi)=f(x)$, which works. Finally for $n=-3$ we have $f(x)=-\cos3x\sin(\frac{4x}{3})$ and $f(x+3\pi)=-\cos(3x+\pi)\sin(\frac{4x}{3}+\pi)=f(x)$.

So $n$ can be any of $\pm2,\pm3$.